# how to stop laravel from getting error if table is null

Tags: php, laravel

i want my code to keep working if the table return null

i tried using if(empty) bla bla bla, but is not seem to be the problem

the problem is laravel don't let me call function on null

```
@php($article = article::find($id)->get())
```

error : "Call to a member function get() on null"

Comment: Your problem is that `article::find($id)` returns null, yes?

Comment: yes, i want to prevent that error

Comment: remove the `->get()`, it does not make sense there, find() will retrive one model or null.

Comment: You don't need `get()`  on `find()` as other users say..but if it returns null you can assign any value to your `$article` using nullcoalesce operator `??`.  `$article = article::find($id) ?? []` if article db returns null `$article` will be assign to empty `array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `aritcle::find($id)` returns null, it should solve the problem:

```php
@if($article = article::find($id) != null)
    // If the aricle::find($id) returns anything but null, this block will be reached.
@endif
```

I think that is better to you to send the data to the view from the controller, instead of using blade directives to fetch data.

something like this:

```php
//Within some controller:
public function show($id)
{
    $article = article::find($id);
    return view('your-view')->with($article);
}
```

Then you can check if `$article` is null using blade:

```php
@if(empty($article))
    // The article is empty
@endif
```

Comment: how to get, a get method from controller?

Comment: i add an example

Answer (score 0):

Using `->get()` after `find()` is unnecessary. `find()` automatically returns the model that matches the primary key provided. You will get errors if you attempt to access `$article` after `find()` fails, but it will stop you from getting the error you posted.